# Correct domain in solution to separable differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$A$, $a$, and $b$ are nonzero constants, and $B$ is any constant. Solve the separable differential equation $Ay' = e^{ay+bx}$ if $y(0) = B$.

The following is my solution. When I enter it into WebWork, I get the message "The domain of your function does not match that of the correct answer."

**Solution**

The given differential equation is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
Ae^{-ay}y^{\prime} = e^{bx} .
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{\mathit{dt}} \Bigl( Ae^{-ay} \Bigr) = -ae^{bx} .
\end{equation*}
According to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
\begin{equation*}
Ae^{-ay} = -\frac{a}{b} \, e^{bx} + C = -\frac{a}{b} \left( e^{bx} - \frac{bC}{a} \right)
\end{equation*}
for a constant $C$. So,
\begin{equation*}
e^{-ay} = -\frac{a}{Ab} \left( e^{bx} - \frac{bC}{a} \right) ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-ay = \ln\left(-\frac{a}{Ab} \left( e^{bx} - \frac{bC}{a} \right)\right) ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
y = -\frac{1}{a} \ln\left(-\frac{a}{Ab} \left( e^{bx} - \frac{bC}{a} \right)\right) .
\end{equation*}
Since $y(0) = B$,
\begin{equation*}
B = -\frac{1}{a} \ln\left(-\frac{a}{Ab} \left( 1 - \frac{bC}{a} \right)\right) ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
e^{-aB} = -\frac{a}{Ab} \left( 1 - \frac{bC}{a} \right) ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
-\frac{Ab}{a} \, e^{-aB} = 1 - \frac{bC}{a} ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{bC}{a} = 1 + \frac{Ab}{a} \, e^{-aB} .
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
y = -\frac{1}{a} \ln\left(-\frac{a}{Ab} \left( e^{bx} - \left[1 + \frac{Ab}{a} \, e^{-aB}\right] \right)\right)
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
y =  -\frac{1}{a} \, \ln\left( \frac{a}{Ab} \Bigl(1 - e^{bx}\Bigr) + e^{-aB} \right) . \ \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Your solution obeys the original differential equation and the initial condition. I would contact your course organiser concerning the WebWorks issue.

Comment: Absolute value in the log ? \begin{equation*}
y =  -\frac{1}{a} \, \ln\left| \frac{a}{Ab} \Bigl(1 - e^{bx}\Bigr) + e^{-aB} \right| . \ \rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}
\end{equation*}

Comment: @JJacquelin That is a legitimate concern. The solution to the differential equation is going to have a certain domain in the case that $a < 0$ and the other constants are positive, and the solution to the differential equation is going to have another domain in the case that all constants are positive.

Comment: @JJacquelin  I did try including absolute value. I got the same message.

Comment: @JJacquelin  I informed the instructor. He said that the answer "looked right" and would forward my concerns to the administrator of the online program.  I will update this post when I get a response from the administrator.